# Specify the reconnection URL in Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When a circuit gets interrupted in Blazor Server and is unable to reconnect, users are shown this prompt.

[image: Blazor reconnection prompt image]

Is there a way of specifying the URL of the hyperlink or retry button in the above image?

Currently it just reloads the root of the site. I would like to have control over the URL that users are sent to.

Comment: [This blog post](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/error-handling/how-can-i-show-a-custom-message-when-a-customers-connection-is-lost-with-the-server) claims that you could provide a custom reconnect message. If this works, you could provide your own message with your own link.

Comment: @UweKeim that worked brilliantly. Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll gladly accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this blog post](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/error-handling/how-can-i-show-a-custom-message-when-a-customers-connection-is-lost-with-the-server) describes, you can provide your very own custom reconnect message. In this custom reconnect HTML fragment, simply provide your own link to your URL.

Microsoft's documentation also shows how to [provide your own UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr#reflect-the-server-side-connection-state-in-the-ui).

Basically, first add a custom HTML to your "Pages/_Host.cshtml" file:

```html
<div id="components-reconnect-modal">
    There was a problem with the connection. 
    Please <a href="https://example.org">click here</a> to reconnect.
</div>
```

Then, add this to your central CSS file:

```css
#components-reconnect-modal {
    display: none;
}

#components-reconnect-modal.components-reconnect-show, 
#components-reconnect-modal.components-reconnect-failed, 
#components-reconnect-modal.components-reconnect-rejected {
    display: block;
}
```

The referred Microsoft documentation has more option to further customize the appearance.